# Were there any clone troopers that didn't have accelerated aging?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

Were there any clone troopers that didn't have accelerated aging? (other than Boba Fett)

Comment: Does Jango Fett count?

Comment: he wasn't technically cloned as far as we know. Thanks though

Comment: Wasn’t Bobba notable for not hving acelarated aging because all the clones had it?

Comment: @DarthEnd3r25 _"he wasn't technically cloned"_ ~ Disambiguation: Jango's "son" (Boba) was a clone freebie that he demanded as part of his price for his DNA, and all the clone troopers were cloned from his DNA so he was "cloned" but wasn't "a clone" ~ Speaking to the question: Boba didn't have accelerated aging but I'm not sure you could say he was a "clone trooper" / pretty sure all the actual troopers had the aging (or at least that there's none mentioned in canon I know of that don't).

Comment: @Scott.Bell : Jango's DNA was the "template" for the clones, his DNA samples were modified to make them more compliant to authority & for accelerated aging / maturity, Boba was a single unmodified clone for him to raise as his son as part of the price for his DNA ~ this is all explicitly stated in conversations in one or more of the movies, so presumably canon.

Answer (score 3):

In Canon, the only Jango Fett clone introduced so far who didn't have modified genes, besides Boba, was [Omega](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Omega), introduced in *The Bad Batch*. In the episode *Bounty Lost*, the clone trooper Tech says that as far as he knows, she and Boba are the only ones:

> Tech: All clones were created from a host named Jango Fett. While our genetic structure was modified for growth acceleration and obedience, Omega is a pure genetic replication.
>
> Hunter: How many clones like that exist?
>
> Tech: To my knowledge there's only one other. A male clone code-named Alpha, later referred to as Boba. Since he disappeared at the start of the war, that makes Omega the sole living source of Fett's raw genetic material.

(source: https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=973&t=44892)